# Pandas - Create new rows and cols based on dict of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please consider the following simplified Pandas dataframe:

| Name | Component |
| --- | --- |
| `D800465` | `[{'component': 'comp1', 'version': '1.0.0'}, {'component': 'comp2', 'version': '15.2.5'}]` |
| `L932227` | `[{'component': 'comp1', 'version': '1.0.0'}, {'component': 'comp2', 'version': '15.2.5'}, {'component': 'comp3', 'version': '2.5'}]` |
| `L908041` | `[{'component': 'comp1', 'version': '1.0.0'}]` |
| `D797502` | `[{'component': 'comp1', 'version': '1.0.0'}]` |

As you understand, the column 'Component' contains lists of dictionnaries, which size may vary.
I want to perform 2 actions on this dataframe: create new columns, 1 for 'ComponentName' and one for 'ComponentVersion'. Beside of this, I want to create any number of rows necessary depnding on the size of my list.

The expected output (with the same exemple as above) should be like this:

| Name | ComponentName | ComponentVersion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `D800465` | `comp1` | `1.0.0` |
| `D800465` | `comp2` | `15.2.5` |
| `L932227` | `comp1` | `1.0.0` |
| `L932227` | `comp2` | `15.2.5` |
| `L932227` | `comp3` | `2.5` |
| `L908041` | `comp1` | `1.0.0` |
| `D797502` | `comp1` | `1.0.0` |

How can I achieve this ?
Thank's a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and convert the dictionaries to columns with [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df2 = df.explode('Component')
df2 = (df2[['Name']].reset_index(drop=True)
       .join(pd.json_normalize(df2['Component']))
      )
```

output:

```
      Name component version
0  D800465     comp1   1.0.0
1  D800465     comp2  15.2.5
2  L932227     comp1   1.0.0
3  L932227     comp2  15.2.5
4  L932227     comp3     2.5
5  L908041     comp1   1.0.0
6  D797502     comp1   1.0.0
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for this perfect answer. I didn't know 'explode'. 
Marked as answer